# Casting chars from input to string

Tags: c++, string, int, validation

fgetc() for proccessing entered chars - char by char.
The function returns integer value of entered char.

I need to check these:

- Each town shouldn't exceed 30 characters
- There exists a "-"(dash) character on each line (splitting the whole line to two cities)

I've defined 31-int-array and one integer for counting chars. When user enter "-", i need to save the chars as a string to another array (actually map).

```
printf("Enter route (city - city):\n");

char town[31];
int character, charsOnRow = 0, i = 0;
map<int, string> route;

while (!feof(stdin)) {
    character = fgetc(stdin);
    if (character != '-' && character != '\n') {
        if (charsOnRow < 30) {
            town[charsOnRow] = character;
            charsOnRow++;
        } else {
            printf("Invalid input.\n");
        }
    } else if (route.size() == 0 && character == '\n') {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    } else {
        town[charsOnRow] = '\0';
        route[i] = town;
        charsOnRow = 0;
    }
}
```

So example of input would be this:

```
Syracuse - Utica
Binghamton - Syracuse
Binghamton - Utica
```

How should i fix it and be able to save int-array to `map<int, string>`?

Comment: you have declared an array of char pointers. I don't think that's what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have both technical errors (invalid C++) and logic errors.

A main cause of that is complexity of doing char-by-char input.

You may find it easier to use C++ level i/o: declare a `std::string` variable to hold a complete *line* of input, read it by using `std::getline`.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `town` as a character array. Currently you have it as a array of character pointer.

Change

```
char * town[31];
```

to

```
char town[31];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually fgetc return an int to indicate error condition, if the value is < 0, you had an error, otherwise, you can simple add it to a string, like:

```
std::string str;
for(;;)
{
  int ch = fgetc(fp);
  if(ch < 0)
    throw error();

  str += ch;
}
```

When you fill up the string, just add it to the map:
map[yourIntValue] = str;

Also, on your code: char * town[31];

This is a array of pointer, the correct for your case is:
char town[31];

And to add it to the map, you can simple use:
map[yourIntValue] = std::string(town);